# HTML Layout Floating

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm just trying to make my website layout. Now I have a problem: right navigation div stays under the Left navigation one. The blue one should be in the same line as the green.
Any suggestions?
I was following this tutorial: http://www.subcide.com/articles/creating-a-css-layout-from-scratch/P6/ and done the same, but it doesn't work as it should be.

[image: My website layout]

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" -->
<html>
<head>
<!-- Svetaines dizainas -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="topmenu">TOPMENU</div>
<div id="topheader">TOP HEADER</div>
<div id="lnav">Left Navigation<div>
<div id="rnav">Right Navigation</div>
<div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body, h1
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}


#container
{
width:1024px;
margin:auto;
}

#topmenu
{
width: 1024px;
background-color:red;
height:53px;
}

#topheader
{
width:1024px;
height:170px;
background-color:orange;
}

#lnav
{
width:1024px;
background-color:green;
}

#rnav
{
width:373px;
float:right;
background-color:blue;
}

#footer
{
width:1024px;
height:190px;
background-color:pink;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#lnav
{
width:1024px;
background-color:green;
}
```

This shouldn't be 1024 right?
Change it to 651px (from my head) to make it fit.
You could ofcourse put it inside the leftmenu and float it right aswell, (make sure the html of right would be above the content of left). But I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: I made mistake in html code :) Anyway, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Arghh my own silly mistake:

```
<div id="lnav">Left Navigation<div>
```

I think you can understand what's wrong :D